# Network clustering stability using bootstrapping techniques

Tags: r, clustering, bootstrap, networks, igraph

I use the standard modularity-maximisation Louvain clustering method to partition a large undirected network into communities. I fear the result of the partition is quite fragile.

Is there a **standard** bootstrapping methodology to get a sense of the precision of my estimate in R for an `igraph` objects?

Resources I found that are partial solutions:

[Bootstrapping networks with R and igraph](https://filipeamteixeira.github.io/posts/2018/04/bootstrapping-networks%20with-r-and-igraph/)

[Bootstrap Evaluation of Clusters](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/09/bootstrap-evaluation-of-clusters/)

[GitHub/Skynet](https://github.com/ropensci/skynet)

[GitHub/Snowboot](https://github.com/cran/snowboot)

[Package ‘DIscBIO’](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DIscBIO/DIscBIO.pdf)

[Package ‘bootnet’](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bootnet/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a standard way, but [here is a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.15047) that discusses one approach. (DISCLAIMER: I know the authors, so take it as you will). There is an [R package](https://github.com/aaamini/nett) implementing the test and a [description](https://aaamini.github.io/nett/reference/snac_test.html) and [examples](https://aaamini.github.io/nett/articles/explore-comm.html) of  how to apply it.

That paper also cites and compares with other approaches such as edge cross-validation and network cross-validation (as well as the spectral test, likelihood-based approaches and so on.) I suggest trying out the cross-validation approaches as well (there is an element of sampling to them). Those also have R code available.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, **modularity maximization is very unstable**: just renumbering vertices, or removing/adding one edge may have a huge impact on obtained results. This was shown for instance in:

[Static community detection algorithms for evolving networks](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00492058)

However, **iterating community detection leads to very stable pieces** in most practical cases:

[Stable community cores in complex networks](http://www.complexnetworks.fr/stable-community-cores-in-complex-networks/)

but not in random graphs:

[The Power of Consensus: Random Graphs Have No Communities](http://www.complexnetworks.fr/the-power-of-consensus-random-graphs-have-no-communities/)